# Should I typehint my dependency injection variables?

Tags: php, interface, dependency-injection, design-patterns

Let's say class Foo requires injection of class Bar.  Should I typehint the method parameter because I know what Bar needs to be, or should I not typehint it, in case Bar changes in the future?

```
class Foo {
    public function __construct( Bar $bar ) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

or:

```
class Foo {
    public function __construct( $bar ) {
        // do something
        // the wrong class could be passed in here, but I'm also future-proof in case
        // another class provides similar functionality to Bar
    }
}
```

Presumably, the "best" answer is to make Bar implement an interface, but I really feel silly creating an interface that will only have one extension class for the foreseeable future.  What is the best practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple, easy solution: typehint to `Bar` for now, and create an interface and change the typehint later.  If you use refactoring practices properly and design your code well, the change should have no effect later on.